# can't use useState with typescript (Cannot find name 'useState')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

What is the problem with below code? I got warning by typescript when use useState

```
import * as React, { useState } from 'react'

const useForm = (callback: any | undefined) => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({}) //error: Cannot find name 'useState'.ts(2304)


  const handleInputChange = event => {
    event.persist()
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }))
  }

  return {
    handleInputChange,
    inputs,
  }
}

export default useForm
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-starter-lmub8

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your import statement is invalid.

You can either import everything as `React` like this:

```
import * as React from 'react';
```

and the access `useState` from the `React` object:

```
 const [inputs, setInputs] = React.useState({})
```

or import `React` as the default and only partially import other names:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
```

And the use `useState` as before:

```
const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});
```

Comment: Tried but still throwing me error: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-starter-lmub8

Comment: ` "react": "16.4.1",` Hooks were only introduced with react `16.8`. Your version of react does not support hooks yet. You might need to consider upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in `formHook.tsx`

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
```

and this in `app.tsx`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
const { inputs, handleInputChange } = useForm;
```

Comment: doesn't work https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-starter-lmub8

Comment: it's work https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-starter-u3j3q , please change `useForm()` to `useForm`

Answer (score 0):

you can first use `React.useState` or import it as individual export. second, you should also specify the event object such as change event or form event.

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {useState} from 'react';
const useForm = (callback: () => void) => {
  const [inputs, setInputs] = useState({});


  const handleInputChange = (event:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    event.persist()
    setInputs(inputs => ({
      ...inputs,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
    }))
  }

  return {
    handleInputChange,
    inputs,
  }
}

export default useForm
```